# AngularJS CRUD - export.update() not calling in server controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm using the following Yeoman full stack AngularJS NPM: [generator-angular-fullstack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-fullstack)

When calling update from the client controller, I receive the following error: `Error: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'User.update')` I'm expecting to see the following in my Web Inspector Logs:

```
'5586c4e7214a22b5efbd1672'
'updateUser Called'  <-- Never routes to server controller
```

server/api/route:

```
//Tried PATCH and PUT
router.patch('/:id', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.update);
//router.put('/:id', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.update);
```

server/api/controller:

```
exports.update = function(req, res, next) {  
    console.log('updateUser Called');   
};
```

client/app/controller:

```
 'use strict';

 angular.module('demoApp')
 .controller('SandboxCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $location, Auth, User)       {

 $scope.getCurrentUser = Auth.getCurrentUser;

 $scope.user = {};
 $scope.profiles = {};
 $scope.allergens = {};

 $http.get('/api/users/me').success(function (user) {
  $scope.user = user;
  $scope.profiles = user.profiles;

  console.log(user.name);
  console.log(user.profiles);
 });

 // Update existing User
 $scope.update = function () {
  var user = $scope.user;

  console.log(user._id);

  User.update(function () {
     $location.path('/' + user._id);
  }, function (errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
     });
   };
});
```

/Client/User/Factory:

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('demoApp')
   .factory('User', function ($resource) {
     return $resource('/api/users/:id/:controller', {
       id: '@_id'
 },
 {
  changePassword: {
    method: 'PUT',
    params: {
      controller:'password'
    }
  },
  update: {   //<-- I was missing this! 
    method: 'PATCH'        
  },
  get: {
    method: 'GET',
    params: {
      id:'me'
    }
   }
   });
 });
```

Comment: Where do you define **User**? It doesn't seem to have a **update** function?

Comment: Updated the client controller to show where User if defined.

Comment: You just show the reference to **User**, but not the **factory/service** function

Comment: Yeah..Can you also provide the service User

Comment: Factory updated and posted, the Logging error went away!  But I'm still not getting the Logger message: 'updateUser called'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AngularJS NPM generator-angular-fullstack, the factory/service is tucked away under /client/components/auth/user.service.js

Added necessary object handle to existing factory solved this issue.

```
update: {   //<-- I was missing this! 
method: 'PATCH'        
},
```